# refer outside class a local variable from class method

Tags: ruby

```
class Person

    attr_accessor :fn, :mn, :ln

    def whole_name
        n = fn + " "
        n = n + "#{mn} " if mn
        n << ln
    end
end


dave = Person.new
dave.fn = "Jim"
puts dave.whole_name
```

Can you please write here the syntax for referring local variable n (from class method whole_name) from outside the class definition?

Thank you.

Comment: Aside: As you have written it, `whole_name` would usually be called an instance method. A "class method" is more often used to describe a method like `new` that you call directly against the class e.g. you might choose to implement `Person.all_last_names` . . . Ruby also uses the term "singleton method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable n is out of scope. You'll need to set up an instance variable getter and call that instead.

If you're confused, attr_accessor is equivalent to defining a getter and setter method:

```
attr_accessor :prop
```

Is the same as

```
def prop
  @prop
end

def prop=(value)
  @prop = value
end
```

Here, @prop is a variable that is maintained separately for each instance of the object. It is not directly visible to another object, but it is exposed via a getter method.